# One dimensional integrals in Green's theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, vector-analysis

I am trying to understand Green's theorem, but the problem is I don't know what is the definition of the integrals in the theorem. This is the expression that one proves to hold with some assumption on multivariate functions $L(x,y)$ and $M(x,y)$:

$$\oint_{C} (L\, dx + M\, dy) = \iint_{D} \left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial y}\right)\, dx\, dy$$
The question is how one defines:
$$\oint_{C} L\, dx$$

I am only looking for a formal definition in terms of Riemann or Lebesgue integral of the last expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really voodoo notation.  Given a vector field $F = L \hat x + M \hat y$, and a curve $\ell(t)$ that traces out $C$ from $t=a$ to $t=b$, the LHS should be understood as

$$\oint_C (L \, dx + M \, dy) \equiv \int_{a}^{b} (F \circ \ell)(t) \cdot \ell'(t) \, dt$$

The notation might make more sense in the context of differential forms, however, if you're familiar with that.

Comment: So the single integral are meaningless, right? No I don't but I would be happy to be guided for a source that explains both :)... thank you!

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say it's meaningless, just that the notation is a bit opaque.  AS for differential forms, that's a rather big topic.  Spivak is a commonly cited first text, but I'm not personally familiar with it.

Comment: Well as far as I understand, the way you made the definition makes single $\oint\limits_{C} Ldx$ meaningless. Oh thanks for the reference although I've read bad things about that. Lets see what can I found. Thank you anyways.

Comment: Ah, well, it would make sense if the path is totally in the $x$ direction (but then how could it be closed?), or if $M = 0$.